# End to end testing of two or more mule applications

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I have multiple mule applications forming one big application. Individual components have been tested but when it comes to automate end to end testing we are finding a way for it.

Application 1 takes an input, processes it and send the processed object to application 2 which processes the input and sends to application 3, output of third application is the final result.

I want to validate the integration among the application 1-2 and 2-3 and then 1-3 also, so that we can easily test whenever there are more applications added to the main application.

Can anyone help me out on this, are there any tools which can be used to test this inside or outside anypoint studio?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Soap UI](https://www.soapui.org/) for your integration and functional testing. You can test for both SOAP,REST and JMS endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how objects are being passed between your applications, however what might work for you is to create "test" mule flows that use an HTTP inbound endpoint, the next step in the flow can setup your object, then you can call your main flow via a flow reference. Something like this:

```
<flow name="testFlow">
       <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
       <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="required input"/>
       <flow-ref name="yourAppFlow" doc:name=""/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is:

1. Find a way to run all your apps with proper configurations
2. Launch your tests and verify the result

You can use the [Mule Maven Plugin multiple application deployment](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-maven-plugin#deploying-multiple-applications) to deploy all your apps. Once deployed, run your end-to-end tests (with MUnit, SoapUI or any other tools).

If you're not familiar with Maven, there's plenty of resources in the [Mule doc](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-maven-with-mule) and all around the web

Answer (score 0):

First of all, am assuming that the 3 applications are up and running.
Then, You can create an Munit test, in which you mock the flow that you want to leave out.
For example, if you are testing application 1 and 3 but not 2, use the mock component to mock the flow reference (or the http call or whichever component calling application 2) and set the payload to the expected outcome of application 2. 
use the same pattern with different alternatives to validate each scenario.